# PS command to get memory, user, process info on IBM AIX and SunOS Solaris

Tags: unix, solaris, aix

I am looking for best PS command to get as much info as possible, mainly memory info like SZ, RSS with userid, pid, complete command/process.

I have two servers IBM AIX and SunOS solaris. I am OK to have two different commands for two servers.

I have tried "ps v", "ps al", "ps aux"  on AIX, but looking for command that gives more info than these commands.

Comment: Perhaps better for ServerFault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a full command line you have to use the ucb (Berkely) version of ps - /usr/ucb/ps
on Solaris.  ps -w does that   Most distributions of Solaris (>=8) don't always seem to have a manpage for it so try here. If you have it is `man -s 1B ps`:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-0210/6m6nb7mif/index.html

Comment: Your answer is very close, I have found that command that is "/usr/ucb/ps auxw"